# How to verify your application was running all day?

Tags: c#, windows

I wrote a windows C# application that is running 24/7 and collecting sensoric data, storing it in a database.

Once every night, I run some algorithmns on the data from the previous day. The results are only useful if the app was active the whole previous day without major breaks (i.e. breaks more than 5 minutes will render results from that day useless).

**Any ideas how to assure the app was running all the time on a day without major breaks?**

- solution should work even if application/windows crashes and is restarted
- it is possible that there is no sensoric data in a long time, even if the app is running

---

**First ideas**

- Increase a database counter for the current day every minute. If the counter reaches the max 1440 minus a tolerance(60 min x 24 hours), the app was up all day. Seems complicated, needs a counter for each day. Will give headache on change from summer to winter time...

Comment: Can't you just save the timestamp when you get the sensor data?

Comment: @metacircle I got that timestamp, but it doesn't help me to know if I got _all data_ that was available in that day. It doesn't tell me if the app was running.

Comment: each minutes write a log file.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Do you see any advantage in writing a log file each minute to increasing a database counter (see my question)?

Comment: Why do you downvote and vote for close this question? Care to remark?

Comment: You are looking for an absolute guarantee across systems. That will prove to be extremely hard. You'll have to define what major breaks are. Any system observing this system can break too. So what would guarantee you that the monitoring isn't broken?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Persist the following two variables (in a database, a file, wherever you want):

1. An **integer**. This will be your *max number of seconds offline*.
2. A **timestamp**. This will be your *last heartbeat*. **This needs to be UTC, to make it DST-proof.**

Make your application do the following every couple seconds:

1. Read the last **timestamp**.
2. Compare it with the current (UTC) timestamp.
3. If the difference is bigger than the **integer**, update the **integer**.
4. Update the **timestamp** with the current UTC timestamp.

Every day, manually inspect the **timestamp**. Reset it to zero when you do so.

Comment: Great UTC hint. And I like the solution too. Thinking about any loopholes right now...

Comment: Only weakness I can think of right now is system clock being messed with, but I don't see this happening with any modern (or minimally robust) systems. Also, such problem would affect any heartbeat-based solutions, as far as I can imagine (including log file and the DB counter you proposed).

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you want to have happen.  Just a few quick ideas off the top of my head.

If you want to restart the app - You could create a Heartbeat windows service that is designed to ensure that the process is running.  If it isn't running you can then have it restart the process.

If you just need/want to validate the data.  Have the application report a health check to the database and use that as a "was it here" the entire time.

Comment: I only need to vaildate the data, restarting is not an issue. Could you please elaborate what you mean with "report a health check"?